# JavaScript Queue

Tags: javascript, queue

I'm new to JS and have I made this snippet for practicing. Because I have no idea for JS conventions, I want some advice about that.

```
function Queue() {
    this.list = new Array();

    this.pop = function() {
        return this.list.pop()
    };

    this.push =  function(el) {
        this.list.unshift(el);
    };

    this.size = function() {
        return this.list.length;
    };

    this.isEmpty = function() {
        return this.size() == 0;
    }

    this.print = function() {
        var res = '(';
        for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length-1; i++) {
            res += this.list[i] + ',';
        }
        res += this.list[this.list.length-1] + ')<br/>';
        document.write(res);
    }

    this.front = function() {
        return this.list[0];
    }

    this.back = function() {
        return this.list[this.list.length-1];
    }
}

/* test code */
var myQueue = new Queue();

myQueue.push(1);
myQueue.print();
myQueue.push(2);
myQueue.print();
myQueue.push(3);
myQueue.print();
myQueue.push(4);
myQueue.print();
myQueue.push(5);
myQueue.print();

myQueue.pop();
myQueue.print();
myQueue.pop();
myQueue.print();
myQueue.pop();
myQueue.print();
myQueue.pop();
myQueue.print();
myQueue.pop();
```

Comment: If your focus is on the JavaScript, I suggest you to remove the HTML around.

Comment: It looks fine. I see no big improvementpotential. But besides that, you realized that you simply wrote a wrapper around a JS _Array_? To practice programming it is okay, but from a _real-world_ point of view, I would rather use the array directly than an abstraction around it. It brings nothing new to the table (besides a "print" function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Thomas Junk said, your wrapper pretty much maps 1:1 to JavaScript's existing, native `Array`. The biggest difference is that your `push` method maps to `Array`'s `unshift` method, which, frankly, is very confusing.

`push` and `pop` - like `shift` and `unshift` - should be "symmetrical", so that the last thing that got `push`ed is what you get back when you call `pop`. But here (if the queue is longer than 1) you get something else back.

Typically, you'd make a queue with a plain `[]`, and then push and *shift* elements on and off to get FIFO behavior.

You code does add a convenience methods for getting the first and last elements (the latter is indeed rather convenient), and a `print`. However, the `print` assumes you're running in a browser (not Node.js), and includes HTML in its output, which makes it less useful. And the logic differs little from the built-in string representation of an `Array`.

Besides, if you want to join all the elements in the array together into a string, there's `join`:

```
var res = "(" + this.list.join(",") + ")<br/>";
```

or the default coerced-to-string representation:

```
var res = "(" + this.list + ")<br/>";
```

Though again, neither one is terribly useful.

Here's how I'd make a queue:

```
var queue = [];
```

and here's how you'd use it:

```
queue.push(1);
queue.push(2);

// don't write to the document object for debugging purposes;
// just use the console
console.log(queue);

queue.shift(); // => 1
queue.shift(); // => 2
```